Next JS - getting the base localhost url to use in client side
I'm using Cognito in my Next JS (v14.0.3) app. To integrate, I utilized aws-amplify library. Following is my aws configuration file
... 

const awsConfig: ResourcesConfig = {
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      userPoolId: NEXT_PUBLIC_USER_POOL_ID,
      userPoolClientId: NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
      loginWith: {
        oauth: {
          domain: NEXT_PUBLIC_COGNITO_DOMAIN,
          scopes: ['openid', 'email', 'profile'],
          redirectSignIn: [BASE_URL],
          redirectSignOut: [BASE_URL],
          responseType: 'code',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

export default awsConfig;


I need my BASE_URL to be http://localhost:3000 when I'm in dev mode, while https://my-prod-site.com when in prod mode. How should I do it?
I tried this
const BASE_URL =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? 'http://localhost:' + process.env.PORT
    : process.env.HOST_URL;

It works on the server side, BASE_URL is getting set to http://localhost:3000. But this export file is used in the client side, so I'm guessing process.env.PORT is rendered undefined, since PORT is not prefixed by NEXT_PUBLIC_. Is updating my environment variables with a NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefixed value my only way?

Here's a suggestion to set up BASE_URL
const BASE_URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
  process.env.PRODUCTION_BASE_URL : (
    typeof window !== 'undefined' ?
      window.location.origin : 'http://localhost:' + process.env.PORT
  )

I'm assuming you can gather your production url https://my-prod-site.com from an environment variable. To match the aforementioned code sample, you can add the following line to your environment variable file (.env / .env.local / .env.preview / .env.test / vercel environment configuration dashboard - whichever is applicable) -
PRODUCTION_BASE_URL=https://my-prod-site.com

You have to remember that Next JS will go through this file twice, once during server side rendering and one in the client side.

When you're in production, it will now use https://my-prod-site.com always
When in dev

During server side rendering, there will be no window variable. It will use process.env.PORT to dynamically set your value. (Btw, just check if PORT is returning undefined, sometimes it might do that, usually when system is relying on default 3000 port value)
During client side rendering, it will fetch your origin url dynamically using window.location.origin.




From the documentation:

In general only one .env.local file is needed. However, sometimes you might want to add some defaults for the development (next dev) or production (next start) environment. Next.js allows you to set defaults in .env (all environments), .env.development (development environment), and .env.production (production environment). .env.local always overrides the defaults set.

In other words, just add a common .env file and one more .env file for each environment (such as .env.production or .env.preview). The values in these environment files will override anything in .env and will be specific to the environment that you want. One nuance, however:

.env.local always overrides the defaults set

Also, keep in mind:

Non-NEXT_PUBLIC_ environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they aren't accessible to the browser (the client runs in a different environment).

This means that you should (usually) be prefixing your environment variables with NEXT_PUBLIC_

Is using the environment variable my only way? The problem with that is url becomes static. If I start my application using a different port, I will again have to update the environment variable.

Yeah. Also, you're likely to have nginx and/or pm2 dynamically mapping your traffic to different ports when you're in production.

I have a BASE_URL in production environment - and that's static. I don't mind keeping it that way. But I need to be able to dynamically figure out the base url while I'm developing instead of setting it statically in my .env.local (or some other env file) file.

Sounds like a different question. You can achieve this with what I've answered above. If you want to query for the base url on the client side, you can do so in a useEffect and window.location
